# What is a syntax to query a first_name of employees and first_name of their managers?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I know how to query first_name of all employees and first_name of all managers of departments separately but do not not know how to query a first_name of employees and first_name of their managers?
The structure of both tables are following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just do self join and use aliases.

`SELECT child.first_name   AS employee_first_name, 
       manager.first_name AS manager_first_name 
FROM   employees as child 
       INNER JOIN employees as manager 
              ON ( child.manager_id = manager.employee_id )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that employee.manager_id points to the manager of an employee.

Then self-join the employees table on the manager_id.

```
SELECT 
 emp.first_name AS emp_first_name, 
 mgr.first_name AS mgr_first_name
FROM employees emp
LEFT JOIN employees mgr 
  ON mgr.employee_id = emp.manager_id
ORDER BY emp.first_name
```

And if you also want the manager of their departement.

```
SELECT 
 emp.first_name AS emp_first_name,
 mgr.first_name AS mgr_first_name,
 depmgr.first_name AS depmgr_first_name
FROM employees emp
LEFT JOIN employees mgr 
  ON mgr.employee_id = emp.manager_id
LEFT JOIN departments dep
  ON dep.department_id = emp.department_id
LEFT JOIN employees depmgr 
  ON depmgr.employee_id = dep.manager_id
ORDER BY emp.first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You would typically start from the `employees` table, then bring in the corresponding record in `departments` (the department he/she belongs to), and finally join again on `employees` to get the firstname of the departmnet manager :

```
select e.firstname employee_firstname, m.firstname manager_first_name
from employees e
inner join departments d on d.department_id = e.department_id
inner join employees m on m.employee_id = d.manager_id
```